# How do I turn a 2D coin texture to a 3D image

Tags: vector, 3d

I have created the following 2D coin texture:

[image: coin textures]

From this 2D textures, I'd like to create something like this:

[image: example]

What is the best way to go about this?
I tried using Blender, and I created this render:

[image: 3d blender render]

Sadly it looks way too realistic. I can't figure out how to make it look less realistic. I tried flat shading which helped, but it still looks weird. I another issue with this is the position of the highlight.

Are these images done by using a perspective tool and creating a 3D looking image in a 2D environment? Or is it done with something like Blender, just changed to make it look less realistic? Or is this done in a completely different way?

Comment: Your "3D" examples aren't actually 3D, They are merely **drawn** in a 2d application to appear that way.  There's no 3D modeler at work there.

Comment: Youtube. Illustrator extrude.

Comment: In 3D, you can get this result with a **toon shader with outline**.

Comment: @Scott Alright, thanks

Comment: @Lucian, I will do that, thankyou

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Interesting. I will try that also

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no 3D modeler at work in your examples. If you look at your sample images, all the highlights are the same, and you can pick out coins which are identical. This is a clear indicator that there's no *actual* 3D taking place.

Coins are drawn in a 2D application with perspective, then duplicated and altered slightly.

A quick rough example....

[image]

You may need to draw 3 or 4 different coins, and then add to the overall "scene" when you have things stacked. But this is essentially how it's done. I drew *one* additional coin, at a different angle, to create the images below.

[image] [image]

Comment: Not an expert, but would removing the black outlines separating the different sides give almost the exact look in the example?

Comment: @Anoplexian-ReinstateMonica if you look at the static image at the bottom, the outlines were removed and a few other things modified and refined. The animation, due to file size (kb), limits what can be shown. The animation is to show the overall **method** and not designed to provide a final, usable, image. In short, sure! `:)` there are a lot of things one could do. This is merely an example. `:)`

Comment: Fair enough, it is an excellent showing. I was curious as to whether the lines themselves were what caused the disconnect to my eye or whether it was the shading of the coin sides not quite matching in color.

Comment: This was, quite literally, thrown together in 2 or 3 minutes. I didn't spend any time at all refining. If I intended to use the artwork, I'd spend much, much, more time polishing. @Anoplexian-ReinstateMonica I removed the lines. `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the animation. This will probably be the attempt that I try. One question, what editor are you using?

Comment: Hi @JackStoller I use Adobe Illustrator.. and I prefer CS6, which is used in the animation. But there's nothing there which couldn't be done in any version of Illustrator, or even Inkscape or another editor. There's no "critical feature" used overall.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Trying it now

Comment: Just wow. Doing this myself would probably take.... long.

Answer (score 6):

Technically speaking you've already done what you set out to do, with blender. But as Scott pointed out the examples you've provided have been drawn from the start in 2D to include a third dimension, and are not actually 3D.

Regarding the "realism", I'd like to point out two things in your examples that stand out to me when compared to your image:

1. The colors are brighter
2. The coins have a black outline

You should try both of these to see if you get the result you're looking for.

Comment: I'll definitely be trying this